# Install Ubuntu on PC with Windows XP Home and Professional

Tags: 14.04

My friend's PC boots up with an option to choose between Windows XP Professional or Windows XP Home Edition.  I am worried that if I install Ubuntu alongside XP it might erase or break the existing Windows boot setup and prevent Windows booting.  The boot options on my friend's PC are:

Microsoft Windows XP Professional

Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition

Only the 'Professional' option actually boots.  Selecting the 'Home' version gives the following error message:

"Windows could not start because of a computer disk hardware configuration problem.  Could not read from the selected boot disk.  Check boot path and disk hardware.  Please check the Windows documentation about hardware disk configuration and your hardware reference manuals for additional information."

So I don't know if there has been an attempt to create another partition for Windows Home that wasn't successful?  The 'Home' boot option is not needed anyway as it is broken.

I have run the live image and gparted says sda1 has one ntfs partition of 37.24Gb (13.28Gb used and 23.96Gb unused) and 8.29Mb of unallocated space.  It is a 40Gb hard drive.

Has anybody had experience of this or knows what will happen if I go ahead and install?

Many thanks to you both for responding, I have edited this question with more info.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: a screenshot from `gparted` or the output to `gparted --list`? Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: regarding your windows xp home, open c:\boot.ini in notepad and remove entry of windows xp home from it.

Comment: @ubuntu99 Great!  Removing the 'home' entry from boot.ini has worked, its now booting straight into Windows.  I've installed Ubuntu alongside windows a few times before so no worries now. I just wanted to make sure as this isn't my own PC and I'm trying to convert my friend to Linux so the last thing I wanted to do was return it with a broke Windows partition.  Many thanks ubuntu99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may install Ubuntu by choosing something else and then shrink your ntfs partition to 20 GB and create ext4 partition from 20 gb free space mounted at root (/), then install. It will work like charm.

Comment: you can thank by clicking the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of the text, which means "I accept the answer"